# Nginx location not working even as expected

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

The following is the configuration I have in my project nginx.conf. When I am trying to access the application by using the url http://localhost:8080/session/ , I am getting the error 404 not found.

The url works fine if I have the location as

```
location / { }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /session {
        root   /app;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are listening on 80 but accessing through 8080

Comment: While running docker build, this is the command i use. The same config works for location / { }

Docker command:
```docker run -d -p 8080:80 container_id```

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried without `/`at the end? (like `http://localhost:8080/session`)

Comment: Yes. I have tried.

Comment: What do you mean `location / { }`? Do you mean with the same three statements between braces?

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile. My guess, the location is working fine, but /app directory is missing.

Comment: You don't need `location / { }`. Is this your entire conf? There could be regex locations that could be short circuiting your configuration

Comment: The below is the code I have used. location without any uri ie (location / {}) is worked fine. But the below configuration is not working fine.
**user  nginx;
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /session {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}}}**

Comment: The ideal issue was with vue js. Not with the NGINX. The base path of the index.html and other compiled css or js scripts are placed in the different location. Hence the issue. It is resolved now.
`module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? './' // prod
    : '/', // dev
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my analysis, the application is created by using Vue and Node JS.

The application needs below procedure to let know the default public path of the scripts. So that, the same could be configured and workable for NGINX. Kind of touching the nose around the face. But yes, the below configuration impacts the NGINX location path as well.

The ideal issue was with vue js. Not with the NGINX. The base path of the index.html and other compiled css or js scripts are placed in the different location. Hence the issue. It is resolved now.

```
module.exports = { 
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === '/'
}
```